# how to make a script run every time i load data from WebMethod using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

i have a problem that javascript script only loaded once when the page is loading,but i need it every time i get data from WebMethod on the server side

here is my code:

My JavaSript ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {

        function InfiniteScroll() {

            $('#divPostsLoader').html('<img src="img/loader.gif">');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home.aspx/GetLastArticles",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != "") {

                        $('#divPostsLoader:last').after(data.d);

                    }
                    $('#divPostsLoader').empty();
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    if (!document.getElementById('#divPostsLoader').innerHTML == "<p>END OF POSTS</p>")
                        $('#divPostsLoader').empty();
                    $('#divPostsLoader').html("<p>END OF POSTS</p>");
                }
            })

        };
        var b = false;
        //When scroll down, the scroller is at the bottom with the function below and fire the lastPostFunc function
        $(window).scroll(function () {

            if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
                InfiniteScroll();

            }

            b = true;
        });
        if (!b) {

            window.onload = function () {
                InfiniteScroll();

            };

        }
    });

</script>
```

and here is my javasript that i want it to fire everytime i get data from `GetLastArticles` WebMethod:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".tag_button").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action - hash doesn't appear in url
        $(this).parent().find('div').toggleClass('tags-active');
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('child');


    });
</script>
```

my aspx page (client side):

```
<div class="tags_list">
                                    <a class="tag-icon tag_button" href="#" >Tags</a>
                                    <div class="tags">
                                        <a class="tag-icon" href="#" >Tag1</a>
                                        <a class="tag-icon" href="#">Tag2</a>
                                        <a class="tag-icon" href="#">Tag3</a>
                                        <a class="tag-icon" href="#">Tag4</a>
                                        <a class="tag-icon" href="#">Tag5</a>
                                        <a class="tag-icon" href="#">Tag6</a>
                                        <a class="tag-icon" href="#">Tag7</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to the following and the eventhandler is attached to dynamically added elements too.

```
$(document).on('click', '.tag_button', function() {...});
```

**Syntax explanation**

Just to clarify the code. The syntax is as follows:

```
$(document).on(events, cssSelector, handler);
```

See the full [API on jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler). By selecting `document` we make sure this event handler is loaded to all elements in the document now and in the future.

Comment: Thanks that really help me alot

Answer (score 1):

call your function in ajax success

```
success: function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
                $('#divPostsLoader:last').after(data.d);
       }
        $('#divPostsLoader').empty();
        $(".tag_button").click();
},
```